# How do I determine if differences between medians are statistically significant when notches are very close (see "C" and "D")?

Tags: boxplot

Regarding "C" and "D":

Is there a way other than visually inspecting the notches from the boxplots? I know the range of values for "D" is lower than "C" and the median value appears to be lower for "D". I also think that box "D" has less variability. I'm not sure what else is worth mentioning when I compare the two boxplots.

[image: Boxplots]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here.

First, I have always regarded notches in boxplots
to be a rough suggestion whether medians are equal.
Notches are calibrated for comparisons, at the 5% level, of two groups at a time.

Using boxplot notches as a graphical device, it is especially
important to show the boxplots in a way that
makes the notches easy to see. In this case, I
think it would be helpful to plot the boxplots horizontally, rather than vertically.
Also, the
notches may be easier to see if the interiors of boxes have
colors that contrast with the outlines.

Thus, I believe the righthand panel below shows the relative
locations of the notches better than does the
lefthand panel. [There are 500 observations in each plot.]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 boxplot(x1,x2, col="grey", notch=T)
 boxplot(x1,x2, notch=T, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Second, I think it is best to do a formal test
whether the locations of the samples differ.
If the distribution types of the populations
are unknown, one can use a nonparametric test.
Results for the Wilcoxon rank sum test are shown
below. There is no doubt about significance
at the 5% level.

```
wilcox.test(x1,x2)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test 
        with continuity correction

data:  x1 and x2
W = 108000, p-value = 0.0001981
alternative hypothesis: 
  true location shift is not equal to 0
```

*Note:* The following R code was used to
simulate my fictitious data. Because populations
are chi-squared, a parametric test might
be used instead.

```
set.seed(2022)
x1 = rchisq(500, 10)
x2 = rchisq(500, 11)
```